# Regarding Customer Automatically logged out after payment

Tags: payment, payment-gateway, customer-session, magento2.3.7

I am facing one issue, May you please help ?
I do added custom payment gateway its working fine but after payment done customer automatically gets logged out from application.
What can be the issue. I also tried disabling Full page Cache but still facing same issue. I am using Magento 2.3.7 version.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems, your issue is related to the **SameSite** issue. Please refer the below links.

https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/26377

https://support.magento.com/hc/en-us/articles/360049032952-Customers-get-logged-out-or-lose-cart-content-on-Magento-storefront

> **Solution:**
> To solve the issue, contact the third-party service provider and request their developers update their integrations to configure cookie parameters.

> **Temporary workaround:**
> To make your integration work while developers of the third-party service provider resolve the issue, you can set SameSite value to None.
> This can be done by configuring headers in Nginx or configuring this parameter via HTTP headers.

Comment: Ohk but is it from server side issue? how can i fix this?

Comment: For apache https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54104573/how-to-set-samesite-cookie-attribute-using-apache-configuration

Comment: Thanks i will check  it

Comment: We can fix it in code as well. Please check the link for the patch.

Comment: which link patch?

Comment: Github issue link which I posted in my answer.

Comment: Hi i checked but still not working..

Comment: Bro Hatsoff to you. Your are right the issue was SameSite so i have downloaded this plugin and works well. Plugin:-https://github.com/Veriteworks/CookieFix